# JWPlayer not running

Tags: html, jwplayer

I have downloaded JWPlayer version 6. I have used the script but i can see the video player

It's just coming blank, not the video nor the player shows up.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("container").setup({
       modes : [{type: 'flash', src:  '<?php echo base_url();?>assets/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf'}], //force flashplayer for video
       image: "<?php echo base_url();?>product_images/nouser.png", //poster image
       file: "<?php echo base_url().$vid[0]['post_file'];?>",  //video file 
       height: "693", //set height in px
       width: "388" //set width in px
   });
</script>
```

below is the total souce of the webpage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>header</title>
    <script src="http://localhost/talent/assets/front_assets/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://localhost/talent/assets/front_assets/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
        <script src="http://localhost/talent/assets/front_assets/js/jquery.flexslider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://localhost/talent/assets/front_assets/js/Placeholders.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script>
function redir()
{
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
        window.location=pathname;
}
</script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function()
                       {
                        $("#sub_butt_reg").click(function()
                                            {
                                             var first_name=$('#first_name').val();
                                             var last_name=$('#last_name').val();
                                             var email=$('#r_email').val();
                                             var password=$('#r_password').val();
                                             var c_password=$('#c_password').val();
                                             //var sec_q=$('#sec_q').val();
                                             //var sec_a=$('#sec_a').val();
                                             //var sex=$('#sex').val();
                                             var contact=$('#contact').val();
                                             //var address=$('#address').val();
                                             //var pin=$('#pin').val();
                                             //var country=$('#country').val();
                                             //var state=$('#state').val();
                                             //var city=$('#city').val();
                                             if(first_name==""||first_name==null)
                                                 alert('Enter First Name');
                                             else if(last_name==""||last_name==null)
                                                 alert('Enter Last Name');
                                             else if(email==""||email==null)
                                                 alert('Enter Email');
                                             else if(password==""||password==null)
                                                 alert('Enter Password');
                                             else if(c_password==""||c_password==null)
                                                 alert('Enter confirm Password');
                                             else if(contact==""||contact==null)
                                                 alert('Enter Contact No');
                                             /*
                                             else if(sex==0)
                                                 alert('Select Sex');
                                             else if(pin==""||pin==null)
                                                 alert('Enter Pin');
                                             else if(address==""||address==null)
                                                 alert('Enter Address');
                                             else if(country==0)
                                                 alert('Select Country');
                                             else if(state==0)
                                                 alert('Select State');
                                             else if(city==0)
                                                 alert('Select City');*/
                                             else
                                              {
                                               $('#add_result').html('<p><img src="http://localhost/talent/assets/front_assets/images/ajax_loader.gif" width="20" height="20" /></p>');
                                               $.post("http://localhost/talent/ajax/register",
                                                       {'first_name':first_name,'last_name':last_name,'email':email,
                                                       'password':password,'c_password':c_password,'contact':contact
                                                       /*,
                                                       'sex':sex,
                                                       'address':address,'pin':pin,
                                                       'country':country,'state':state,
                                                       'city':city*/
                                                       },function(data)
                                                                           {
                                                                             //alert(data); 
                                                                             $('#add_result').html(data);
                                                                             if(data=="Successfully Registered' Please Log-In.Mail Send To Your Email-ID")
                                                                                 {
                                                                                   $("#sub_butt_reg").hide();
                                                                                   $("#can_butt").hide();
                                                                                   $("#red_reg").show();
                                                                                 }
                                                                                                                                                                }

                                                      );

                                              }
                                            });


                           $("#p_register").click(function()
                                            {
                                             var first_name=$('#p_first_name').val();
                                             var last_name=$('#p_last_name').val();
                                             var email=$('#p_email').val();
                                             var password=$('#p_password').val();
                                             var c_password=$('#pc_password').val();
                                             //var sec_q=$('#sec_q').val();
                                             //var sec_a=$('#sec_a').val();
                                             //var sex=$('#sex').val();
                                             var contact=$('#p_contact').val();
                                             //var address=$('#address').val();
                                             //var pin=$('#pin').val();
                                             //var country=$('#country').val();
                                             //var state=$('#state').val();
                                             //var city=$('#city').val();
                                             if(first_name==""||first_name==null)
                                                 alert('Enter First Name');
                                             else if(last_name==""||last_name==null)
                                                 alert('Enter Last Name');
                                             else if(email==""||email==null)
                                                 alert('Enter Email');
                                             else if(password==""||password==null)
                                                 alert('Enter Password');
                                             else if(c_password==""||c_password==null)
                                                 alert('Enter confirm Password');
                                             else if(contact==""||contact==null)
                                                 alert('Enter Contact No');
                                             /*
                                             else if(sex==0)
                                                 alert('Select Sex');
                                             else if(pin==""||pin==null)
                                                 alert('Enter Pin');
                                             else if(address==""||address==null)
                                                 alert('Enter Address');
                                             else if(country==0)
                                                 alert('Select Country');
                                             else if(state==0)
                                                 alert('Select State');
                                             else if(city==0)
                                                 alert('Select City');*/
                                             else
                                              {
                                               $('#add_result').html('<p><img src="http://localhost/talent/assets/front_assets/images/ajax_loader.gif" width="20" height="20" /></p>');
                                               $.post("http://localhost/talent/ajax/register",
                                                       {'first_name':first_name,'last_name':last_name,'email':email,
                                                       'password':password,'c_password':c_password,'contact':contact
                                                       /*,
                                                       'sex':sex,
                                                       'address':address,'pin':pin,
                                                       'country':country,'state':state,
                                                       'city':city*/
                                                       },function(data)
                                                                           {
                                                                             //alert(data); 
                                                                             $('#register_message').html(data);
                                                                             if(data=="success Registrations Successfull. Visit your email-id for more details")
                                                                                 {
                                                                                   $("#get_back").show();
                                                                                   //$("#can_butt").hide();
                                                                                   $("#register_div_p").hide();
                                                                                 }
                                                                                                                                                                }

                                                      );

                                              }
                                            });                 




                           }
    );
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
         logged as ::saswat.saz.routroy@gmail.com        <br/>
        <br/>
        <a href="http://localhost/talent/">Home</a> 
                <a href="http://localhost/talent/user/logout">Logout</a>
        <a href="http://localhost/talent/user/upload_video">Upload Video</a>
              <a href="http://localhost/talent/video/">See Video</a> 


<br/>
<br/>
<object width='439' height='275' id='flvPlayer'>
  <param name='allowFullScreen' value='true'>
  <param name='movie' value='http://localhost/talent/assets/player/OSplayer.swf?movie=http://localhost/talent/post_files/feb641027629b6a7ba78fb47063c6763vid.flv&btncolor=0x333333&accentcolor=0x20b3f7&txtcolor=0xffffff&volume=&previewimage=previewimageurl&autoload=on'>
  <embed src='http://localhost/talent/assets/front_assets/player/OSplayer.swf?movie=http://localhost/talent/post_files/feb641027629b6a7ba78fb47063c6763vid.flv&btncolor=0x333333&accentcolor=0x20b3f7&txtcolor=0xffffff&volume=&previewimage=previewimageurl&autoload=on' width='439' height='275' allowFullScreen='true' type='application/x-shockwave-flash'>
 </object>

<a href="http://localhost/talent/">Home</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/talent/assets/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("container").setup({
       modes : [{type: 'flash', src:  'http://localhost/talent/assets/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf'}], //force flashplayer for video
       image: "http://localhost/talent/product_images/nouser.png", //poster image
       file: "http://localhost/talent/post_files/feb641027629b6a7ba78fb47063c6763vid.flv",  //video file 
       height: "693", //set height in px
       width: "388" //set width in px
   });
</script>

<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: the issue is that on localhost its not running, but on server its running fine.

Comment: Hard to tell why it wouldn't work locally, then.